# How to evalute: $\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-ax}}{ax} -\frac{e^{-abx}}{1- e^{-ax}}((1-x)\cos (\pi x) + \frac{3}{\pi} \sin(\pi x)) dx$ and $a, b >0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

How to evalute: $$\int_0^1 \left[ \frac{e^{-ax}}{ax} -\frac{e^{-abx}}{1- e^{-ax}}\left((1-x)\cos (\pi x) + \frac{3}{\pi} \sin(\pi x)\right) \right] dx$$ and $a, b >0$

Comment: what about $a,b$ and $t$?

Comment: $a, b > 0$ and istead $t$ is $x$

Comment: It looks like there is a non-integrable singularity in $x=0$, are you sure you wrote it right?

Comment: Maybe the OP meant $1-e^{-a x}$ in the denominator.

Comment: Now is ok. Sorry